# Point in polygon special case

Tags: polygon

The two most common point in polygon test methods (Ray casting method and Winding number method) does not work in my case, when the polygon looks like below:
[image: weird polygon] 
As you can see, the polygon is splitted by the boundaries of coordinate system. Points **A** and **B** are **inside**, **C** is **outside**. All of the methods posted in other threads failed for such polygon. Any idea or a good algorithm? A working C# implementation would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I've found the solution.

But first a better visualization of the problem, below is the polygon displayed on the surface of a cylinder, where the vertical dashed line represent both beginning and end of X coordinate range of values:
[image: Cylindric]

The original polygon must be divided into 2 subpolygons by the coordinate system boundary "line" and algorithm must be executed on those 2 subpolygons.

For drawing or any visualization however still the original polygon must be used.